# Ordered List With Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, codable

I am working with a class which is both `NSManagedObject` and `Codable`. It's a `Feed` and it has multiple `Albums`. I want the ordered list of `Albums` but Core Data forces me to use Set instead, which is not ordered. I can use `NSOrderedSet`, but it doesn't work well with `Codable`. What would be the best way to get the ordered list in Core Data. Below is the Model I am trying to make work.

```
public class Feed: NSManagedObject, Codable {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Feed> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Feed>(entityName: "Feed")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var albums: Set<Album>
    @NSManaged public var feedContainer: FeedContainer?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case albums = "results"
        case feedContainer
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(albums, forKey: .albums)
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Feed", in: managedObjectContext) else {  fatalError("Failed to decode Subject!")  }
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title) ?? ""
        albums = try container.decodeIfPresent(Set<Album>.self, forKey: .albums) ?? []
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use an NSArray? And why doesn't NSOrderedSet work well with Codable?

Comment: I'd recommend to use native Set<> and sort the items accordingly when being displayed. This is more efficient than using ordered sets

Comment: @vadian I have thought about that, but my data doesn't include any field to sort though. It's just a list of albums and it doesn't contain any field which would give us an order.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the ordered list of Albums

It is *your* job to *give* the Album entity an attribute to sort by. Then, when you fetch, you can pass a sort descriptor to receive the Albums sorted on that attribute.

Comment: I am not sure how I can do that though. How can I create an attribute which is consistent with the order of albums coming from network?

Comment: Your question says nothing about "coming from" a "network". You asked about how to make results from core data be "ordered" and I answered about how you do that. Core data results have no natural "order"; it is up to you to provide one, by means of an attribute. You can use a timestamp, an index number, whatever.